# LDAP query not in subquery

Tags: ldap

What I'm trying is to get only the active users and exclude inactive ones (the only difference is inactive users have a value for `accountExpires`).

So I have the expired users query that is:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(!accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(!accountExpires=0))
```

What I need now is how to add the first part of the query that is:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" & userVariable & "*))
```

So the query should be something like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" & userVariable & "*)) NOT IN (&(objectClass=user)(!accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(!accountExpires=0))
```

I know there is not a "not in" expression in LDAP, but how can I get this query?
If I negate the query of expired users it does not work.

Hope somebody has found a solution for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I negate the query of expired users it does not work.

I think this is the issue: you have to properly distribute the negation according to boolean algebra.

The full filter becomes:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=*" & userVariable & "*)(|(!accountExpires=*)(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(accountExpires=0)))
```

*Query Explanation*

If we have a boolean expression *p*∧*q*, the proper negation is ¬*p*∨¬*q*. Thus, to exclude expired users and include only un-expired users, we need the filter:

```
(|(!accountExpires=*)(accountExpires=9223372036854775807)(accountExpires=0))
```

This will include users who have no value for `accountExpires` (see [attribute presence clause](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Presence%20SearchFilter)) or which have [infinite expiration](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/AccountExpires).

I simply converted the `&` to an `|` and reversed the negations, but I think the inclusion of `!accountExpires=*` is also necessary.